# What's the best way to merge to the same table several times in Postgresql?

Tags: postgresql

I'm pretty new to Postgresql and I'm trying to write a fairly complex select query to get the data I need for a report. There's a table I want to merge to that contains the names associated with all the values we need for measures (for example, the option "MALE" has a value of 384 in the main data table). It's easy enough to join to the items table for one of the columns I want to replace, but I have several columns I want to join to the same table and I'm not sure the best way to go about this. I know that I can create a bunch of temporary tables to use in joins, but I'd like to ideally like to just run one query if possible and not have to worry about creating and dropping temp tables.

```
SELECT helpline_calls.id, 
       helpline_calls.call_id, 
       fam_id, 
       family, 
       high_priority, 
       sent_fam_nav, 
       clear_fam_nav, 
       call_back_count, 
       start_time, 
       end_time, 
       phone, 
       helpline_calls.NAME, 
       address_1, 
       address_2, 
       city, 
       zip_code, 
       helpline_calls.email, 
       age, 
       approximate, 
       is_spanish, 
       other_translation, 
       is_professional, 
       followup_date, 
       followup_time, 
       market_agency, 
       market_school, 
       contracted, 
       res_referrals, 
       cps, 
       emergency, 
       conference, 
       no_referrals, 
       send_fam_nav, 
       post_adopt, 
       crisis_response, 
       requested_materials, 
       third_party, 
       complete, 
       pact, 
       mst, 
       connections, 
       helpline_calls.created_at, 
       helpline_calls.updated_at, 
       state_id, 
       whos_calling_id, 
       gate_id, 
       helpline_calls.call_reason_id, 
       tmptblcallreason2.call_reason, 
       (SELECT l_list_items.NAME 
        FROM   helpline_calls 
               JOIN l_list_items 
                 ON helpline_calls.call_reason_id = l_list_items.id 
        WHERE  l_list_items.list_code = 'cc') AS Call_Reason, 
       l_list_items.NAME                      AS Call_type, 
       market_categories.cat_code             AS MarketCategory_Code, 
       market_categories.text                 AS MarketCategory_Code_Text, 
       market_codes.cat_code                  AS Market_Code, 
       market_codes.text                      AS Market_codes_text, 
       problem_categories.code                AS Problemcategory_code, 
       problem_categories.text                AS probelmcategory_text, 
       problem_codes.cat_code                 AS problem_code, 
       problem_codes.text                     AS Problem_code_text, 
       CASE 
         WHEN helpline_calls.pact_offered_id = 603 THEN 'Offered' 
         WHEN helpline_calls.pact_offered_id = 604 THEN 'Accepted' 
       END                                    AS pact_offered, 
       CASE 
         WHEN helpline_calls.mst_offered_id = 603 THEN 'Offered' 
         WHEN helpline_calls.mst_offered_id = 604 THEN 'Accepted' 
       END                                    AS mst_offered, 
       CASE 
         WHEN helpline_calls.connections_offered_id = 603 THEN 'Offered' 
         WHEN helpline_calls.connections_offered_id = 604 THEN 'Accepted' 
       END                                    AS connections_offered, 
       CASE 
         WHEN helpline_calls.crisis_response_offered_id = 603 THEN 'Offered' 
         WHEN helpline_calls.crisis_response_offered_id = 604 THEN 'Accepted' 
       END                                    AS crisis_response_offered, 
       CASE 
         WHEN helpline_calls.sex_id = 384 THEN 'Male' 
         WHEN helpline_calls.sex_id = 385 THEN 'Female' 
         WHEN helpline_calls.sex_id = 386 THEN 'Unknown' 
       END                                    AS Sex, 
       counties.NAME                          AS County, 
       helpline_calls.region_id, 
       family_phone_id, 
       include_on_fam_nav_rpt, 
       users.username, 
       CASE 
         WHEN helpline_calls.is_callback_id = 598 THEN 'Yes' 
         WHEN helpline_calls.is_callback_id = 599 THEN 'No' 
       END                                    AS Call_back_id, 
       CASE 
         WHEN helpline_calls.is_callback_90_days_id = 578 THEN 'Yes' 
         WHEN helpline_calls.is_callback_90_days_id = 579 THEN 'No' 
         WHEN helpline_calls.is_callback_90_days_id = 580 THEN 'Declined' 
       END                                    AS callback_90_days_id, 
       needs_callback, 
       needs_callback_90_days, 
       con_call_type, 
       review, 
       adult_only_prevention, 
       complete_message, 
       sent_fam_nav_date_time, 
       fam_nav_email_flag 
FROM   PUBLIC.helpline_calls 
       JOIN users 
         ON helpline_calls.user_id = users.id 
       LEFT JOIN counties 
              ON helpline_calls.county_id = counties.id 
       LEFT JOIN problem_categories 
              ON helpline_calls.problem_category_id = problem_categories.id 
       LEFT JOIN problem_codes 
              ON helpline_calls.problem_code_id = problem_codes.id 
       LEFT JOIN market_codes 
              ON helpline_calls.market_code_id = market_codes.id 
       LEFT JOIN market_categories 
              ON helpline_calls.market_category_id = market_categories.id 
       LEFT JOIN l_list_items 
              ON helpline_calls.call_type_id = l_list_items.id 
       LEFT JOIN tmptblcallreason2 
              ON helpline_calls.call_id = tmptblcallreason2.call_id 
WHERE  ( start_time BETWEEN '1/1/2019' AND '10/31/2019 11:59:59 PM' ) 

SELECT helpline_calls.call_id, 
       call_reason_id, 
       l_list_items.NAME AS call_reason 
INTO   temp table tmptblcallreason2 
FROM   helpline_calls 
JOIN   l_list_items 
ON     helpline_calls.call_reason_id = l_list_items.id
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use a CTE like this:

```
WITH tmptblcallreason2 AS (
 SELECT helpline_calls.call_id, 
       call_reason_id, 
       l_list_items.NAME AS call_reason  
 FROM   helpline_calls 
 JOIN   l_list_items 
 ON     helpline_calls.call_reason_id = l_list_items.id
),
main_cte AS (
SELECT helpline_calls.id, 
       helpline_calls.call_id, 
       fam_id, 
       family, 
       high_priority, 
       sent_fam_nav, 
       clear_fam_nav, 
       call_back_count, 
       start_time, 
       end_time, 
       phone, 
       helpline_calls.NAME, 
       address_1, 
       address_2, 
       city, 
       zip_code, 
       helpline_calls.email, 
       age, 
       approximate, 
       is_spanish, 
       other_translation, 
       is_professional, 
       followup_date, 
       followup_time, 
       market_agency, 
       market_school, 
       contracted, 
       res_referrals, 
       cps, 
       emergency, 
       conference, 
       no_referrals, 
       send_fam_nav, 
       post_adopt, 
       crisis_response, 
       requested_materials, 
       third_party, 
       complete, 
       pact, 
       mst, 
       connections, 
       helpline_calls.created_at, 
       helpline_calls.updated_at, 
       state_id, 
       whos_calling_id, 
       gate_id, 
       helpline_calls.call_reason_id, 
       tmptblcallreason2.call_reason, 
       (SELECT l_list_items.NAME 
        FROM   helpline_calls 
               JOIN l_list_items 
                 ON helpline_calls.call_reason_id = l_list_items.id 
        WHERE  l_list_items.list_code = 'cc') AS Call_Reason, 
       l_list_items.NAME                      AS Call_type, 
       market_categories.cat_code             AS MarketCategory_Code, 
       market_categories.text                 AS MarketCategory_Code_Text, 
       market_codes.cat_code                  AS Market_Code, 
       market_codes.text                      AS Market_codes_text, 
       problem_categories.code                AS Problemcategory_code, 
       problem_categories.text                AS probelmcategory_text, 
       problem_codes.cat_code                 AS problem_code, 
       problem_codes.text                     AS Problem_code_text, 
       CASE 
         WHEN helpline_calls.pact_offered_id = 603 THEN 'Offered' 
         WHEN helpline_calls.pact_offered_id = 604 THEN 'Accepted' 
       END                                    AS pact_offered, 
       CASE 
         WHEN helpline_calls.mst_offered_id = 603 THEN 'Offered' 
         WHEN helpline_calls.mst_offered_id = 604 THEN 'Accepted' 
       END                                    AS mst_offered, 
       CASE 
         WHEN helpline_calls.connections_offered_id = 603 THEN 'Offered' 
         WHEN helpline_calls.connections_offered_id = 604 THEN 'Accepted' 
       END                                    AS connections_offered, 
       CASE 
         WHEN helpline_calls.crisis_response_offered_id = 603 THEN 'Offered' 
         WHEN helpline_calls.crisis_response_offered_id = 604 THEN 'Accepted' 
       END                                    AS crisis_response_offered, 
       CASE 
         WHEN helpline_calls.sex_id = 384 THEN 'Male' 
         WHEN helpline_calls.sex_id = 385 THEN 'Female' 
         WHEN helpline_calls.sex_id = 386 THEN 'Unknown' 
       END                                    AS Sex, 
       counties.NAME                          AS County, 
       helpline_calls.region_id, 
       family_phone_id, 
       include_on_fam_nav_rpt, 
       users.username, 
       CASE 
         WHEN helpline_calls.is_callback_id = 598 THEN 'Yes' 
         WHEN helpline_calls.is_callback_id = 599 THEN 'No' 
       END                                    AS Call_back_id, 
       CASE 
         WHEN helpline_calls.is_callback_90_days_id = 578 THEN 'Yes' 
         WHEN helpline_calls.is_callback_90_days_id = 579 THEN 'No' 
         WHEN helpline_calls.is_callback_90_days_id = 580 THEN 'Declined' 
       END                                    AS callback_90_days_id, 
       needs_callback, 
       needs_callback_90_days, 
       con_call_type, 
       review, 
       adult_only_prevention, 
       complete_message, 
       sent_fam_nav_date_time, 
       fam_nav_email_flag 
FROM   PUBLIC.helpline_calls 
       JOIN users 
         ON helpline_calls.user_id = users.id 
       LEFT JOIN counties 
              ON helpline_calls.county_id = counties.id 
       LEFT JOIN problem_categories 
              ON helpline_calls.problem_category_id = problem_categories.id 
       LEFT JOIN problem_codes 
              ON helpline_calls.problem_code_id = problem_codes.id 
       LEFT JOIN market_codes 
              ON helpline_calls.market_code_id = market_codes.id 
       LEFT JOIN market_categories 
              ON helpline_calls.market_category_id = market_categories.id 
       LEFT JOIN l_list_items 
              ON helpline_calls.call_type_id = l_list_items.id 
       LEFT JOIN tmptblcallreason2 
              ON helpline_calls.call_id = tmptblcallreason2.call_id 
WHERE  ( start_time BETWEEN '1/1/2019' AND '10/31/2019 11:59:59 PM' ) 
)
SELECT * FROM main_cte
```

Comment: Thanks! You saved me hours of frustration.